# Ambiguity with term "Nationality"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I do not really understand what nationality is.

The table is from 
https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-nationality-and-citizenship.html
[image: table]

If nationality represents a place of birth of an individual, so can I say that Vitaliy Klychko has Kazakh Nationality? He was born there and lived there for some period of time, but he does not have any connection with that country.

Info from wiki about Vitaliy Klychko  (Ukrainian famous boxer)

> Nationality   Ukrainian
>
> Born  19 July 1971 (age 47) Belovodskoye, Kirghiz SSR, Soviet Union (now Kyrgyzstan)

Wiki says *Nationality: Ukrainian*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citizenship_and_nationality#Definitions

Comment: I would not consider either the website or the author of this article reliable authorities in this matter, and dispute not only many of the assertions in the table, but the phrasing of them (*taken birth* is decidedly non-standard, and the concept of *reversing* citizenship or nationalitty also defies the definitions of any of those words). *[The Economist](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2017/07/09/what-is-the-difference-between-nationality-and-citizenship)* would be a far more reliable source,

Answer (score 1):

Nationality is a complex issue.  It is more to do with what you feel is your country than any strict definition.

The table is wrong to assert nationality represents "place of birth". You may not feel a connection to a country that you happened to be born in. For example a person born in Khazakstan to Ukrainian parents may feel a closer connection to Ukraine than Khazakstan.

A person may be born in Russia, but identify as being Chechen, or Ukrainian, or Yakutsk, or from one of the many nationalities found in Russia.  A person may be born in England, but identify as both English and Romani. Or have parents from with different nationalities and identify with both of their parent's nationalities.

It is possible to have a complex of connections. Nationality is complex. The table greatly oversimplifies it.

Comment: And while the two concepts, identity and legality, are distinct, they are not always separated by those terms. We often talk of "British nationals" etc, to refer to citizenship, or legal nationality. Heck, we haven't used citizenship as usual legal term in the UK for very long. Part of the whole "subjects, not citizens" thing. Though for a while that was just a matter for pedants.

Then, of course, we have the four nations of the United Kingdom. Really, to get into this properly we'd need to do the rise of the nation-state & everything. But that's beyond being an English language thing.